# Mysql DELETE with SELECT(?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and i am a little confused...

```
      |products|                          
________________________
|  id  | products_name |
|______________________|
|   1  |  iphone4      |
|   2  |  htc desire   |
    etc.............


     |special_price|
________________________
|  id  | products_price|
|______________________|
|   1  |  400          |
|   2  |  500          |
    etc.............
```

All i want to do is:

```
DELETE (ALL) FROM special_price WHERE products_name='iphone4'
```

How can this happen?

Comment: Why don't you just DELETE FROM special_price WHERE products_name='iphone4' ?

Comment: @Li0liQ: because `products_name` is in another table.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Sorry, I've overlooked that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the id(s) for that product_name, try this:

with IN: (useful for complex conditions)

```
DELETE FROM special_price 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM products WHERE products_name = 'iphone4' )
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DELETE sp FROM special_price sp
INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = sp.id
WHERE p.products_name = "iphone4";
```

Comment: this will delete from sp table only

Comment: Yes, correct. That's what I meant. OP probably doesn't want to delete the product itself, just the special offer on it.

Comment: I think you meant to write: `DELETE sp FROM ...` so rows only from table `special_price` are deleted.